# What is the best way to save the application status data in following condition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have enable push notification from my application on button click .Also push notification will be disabled on on button click . when I stop the application all the data will be lost hence even if the push notifications are enabled then next time when i am running the application then it become disabled.I have to store the state of the push notification some where whether is it enabled or disabled which is the best place to store the state ? One is the database which i know is anything other than database ?

Comment: what you want?? store the push notifications data somewhere??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use The following Code Which uses `NSUserDefaults` to save the state.

```
-(IBAction)disableNotification:(id)sender
{

[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"Disabled" forKey:@"NotificationState"]

}

-(IBAction)EnableNotification:(id)sender
{

[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"Enabled" forKey:@"NotificationState"]

}
```

if you Want to Do something for state

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueforkey:@"NotificationState"]isEqualsToString:@"Enabled"])
{
// Do Some Stuff  

// Enabled State
}

else
{
// Do some Stuff

// Disabled state

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

NSUserDefaults is the best way to save the application state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [core data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) if long text needs to be stored. If you can manage with dictionary values you can go with [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the status of Push Notification in "NSUserDefaults". So that, you can get it's value when you re-open the app.

Please have a look at below tutorial for "NSUserDefaults".

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Cheers.